# How to open different popups with the same title in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, popup, casperjs

I'm trying to automate some tasks using casperJS, and I need to open multiple popups. However, all popups have the exact same url (http://.../printit.aspx/...), so that whenever I use

```
this.withPopup(/printit/, function() {...});
```

it always opens the first popup. I can't access the other ones.

I suppose there are two possibilities :

- close each popup after visiting it, but I can't find how to do this
- accessing popups using another way than the URL regex /printit/. Maybe using `casper.popups`, but the documentation is very vague about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy and documented way of disambiguating two popups. The documentation says that `casper.popups` is an array-like property. So you could iterate over it. Judging [by the code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/05ac9c5999f9b9c8cf387ef717c29cfbb3e91845/modules/casper.js#L145), the `popups` property itself is a [`pagestack`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/05ac9c5999f9b9c8cf387ef717c29cfbb3e91845/modules/pagestack.js). One can easily modify the [`pagestack.findByRegExp()`](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/05ac9c5999f9b9c8cf387ef717c29cfbb3e91845/modules/pagestack.js#L109-L124) function to do this kind of thing.

It seems that the `casper.popups` property contains duplicate entries, so one can filter them out.

```
casper.findAllPopupsByRegExp = function(regexp){
    var popups = this.popups.filter(function(popupPage) {
        return regexp.test(popupPage.url);
    });
    if (!popups) {
        throw new CasperError(f("Couldn't find popup with url matching pattern %s", regexp));
    }

    // remove duplicates
    var uniquePopups = [];
    popups.forEach(function(p){
        if (uniquePopups.indexOf(p) === -1) {
            uniquePopups.push(p);
        }
    });
    return uniquePopups;
}
```

`casper.withPopup()` accepts three types of inputs to identify a popup page. The third one is a the page object itself. So you can retrieve the matching popup page objects with `findAllPopupsByRegExp()`, select the one that you want and pass that to `withPopup()` to change into its context:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var popups = this.findAllPopupsByRegExp(/printit/);
    this.withPopup(popups[1], function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: This works great. However I don't understand the structure of the popups array, it contains many more elements than the number of opened popups, and they seem to point to duplicated popups.

Comment: Great, I hadn't tested this. Regarding your question, this is entirely undocumented and one is not supposed to do stuff in there. CasperJS either has bugs or the duplicate entries are needed for something. I added a filter to remove the duplicate element.

Comment: The new bit does't work, unfortunately : it throws a TypeError when trying to evaluate uniquePopups.indexOf(p)

Comment: Hm, strange. I don't know a page with popups off the top of my head. Can you give me a link so I can test this? Also, I had a typo in the comparison.

Comment: Sorry, it was the typo. Works great !

Comment: @ArtjomB. Few years old thread... Not sure about `popups[1]`... why 1?! Also, with your solution are we sure we are not getting a popup already used?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have a list of links. Every link calls some javascript that opens a new tab(=popup in casperjs), always with the same url (`...\View.aspx`).
Inside the tab i have to click a button that changes the url in the tab  (`...\List.aspx`).
`on("popup.loaded"...)` is called twice, pushing every new page in the `casper.popups` array. They usually alternate, but for some reason (i guess asyncrony) not always: sometimes `casper.popups[/*LAST*/].url` matches `/View\.aspx/`, sometimes it matches `/List\.aspx/`.
I always had to use `casper.withPopup( /*LAST VIEW.ASPX LOADED*/, ...)`; that was not always the last popup loaded and neither the one matching `/View.aspx/` (it could be one of the oldes), so i had to find the latest loaded matching `/View\.aspx/`.
Here's my solution:

```
var is_view_loaded=false;

casper.on('popup.loaded', function(page) {
    if(page.url.match(/View\.aspx/)) {
        is_view_loaded=true;
    }
}

// return last popup which url matches the required regexp
casper.getLastRegExPopup=function(regex) {
    var l=casper.popups.length;
    var i=l-1;
    while(!regex.test(casper.popups[i].url)) {
        i--;
        if(i<0) return null;
    }
    return casper.popups[i];
}
```

Then in my core steps:

```
.
.
// clicked the link, must wait for popup (but which?!)

casper.waitFor(
    function test() {
        return is_view_loaded;
    },
    function then() {
        var popup=casper.getLastRegExPopup(/View\.aspx/);
        casper.withPopup(popup, function() {
            // do things with "this"
        });
        is_view_loaded=false;
    }
    //, timeout
);
.
.
```